# Passing objects between routes Flask Python

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I need to be able to access an object from one route in other routes. If I only need textual data, using session variables work just fine, but what if I want to be able to access an "unjasonyfyble" object?

I managed to do it with **GLOBAL VARIABLES**, I just don't know if this is a good practice...

Below is the code snippet where I got it working, but please, I'd like a general case opinion.

The route:

```
@main.route('/start', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def start():
    global my_form
    my_form = Form()
```

The form class

```
class Form(FlaskForm):
    data = IntegerField('Data', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Next')
```

and then, on any other function, I just access my_form.data.data

I'd really like to do this the right way.

Comment: The obvious and most basic solution is to save the data to a database. Web applications are stateless in between requests and you should never assume you can store state in the app itself. What if your app restarts in between requests? What if you start to scale horizontally and work is distributed? Your state would be lost with globals. Use a persistent cache like Redis or just store it in a datastore like MySQL or Postgres. Keep state data out of your application.